# missing library to create a project in ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem when I create an application in Rails

Using Rails 4.1.0 and ruby ruby ​​2.0.0p451

I get this message:

This line worries me .Is there a problem with spring?

> Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a
>   bundled gem is installed.
>            run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
>   * bin/rake: spring inserted
>   * bin/rails: spring inserted

Comment: This is a normal output as far as I know. You have any other error message?

Comment: That is not an error, everything should be working ok.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin   run bundle exec spring binstub --all * bin/rake: spring inserted * bin/rails: spring inserted  This line worries me .Is there a problem with spring?